# Constructor with array parameters

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I want to make a constructor with array and array size so I can call the object using this: `Multime m1 = Multime({1, 2, 3}, 3);` 
Or should I use **std::vector** instead?

```
class Multime
{
private:
    int elemente[100];
    int size;
public:
    Multime(){}
    Multime(int el[50], int s){
        this -> size = s;
        for(int i = 0; i < this -> size; i++)
            this -> elemente[i] = el[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Multime m1 = Multime({1, 2, 3}, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

And i'm getting **No matching constructor for initialization of 'Multime'**

Comment: Is elemente supposed to always contains 100 elements ?

Comment: How about using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as argument?

Comment: Are you sure `{1, 2, 3}` evaluates to an array of integers?

Comment: You cannot pass arrays as parameters. For more information, see the chapter in your C++ book that explains how function parameters types get decayed. In post-C++11 word you can declare a `std::initializer_list` parameter and avoid the need to pass an explicit array size parameter, and this will work; but this is a fairly advanced topic, see your C++ book for the details.

Comment: By the way, as mentioned you can't pass C-style arrays as arguments as simply as that. Like in C an argument declaration like `int el[]` (size is irrelevant) will be treated as `int* el`, in other words the function expects a pointer as argument. Your compiler should have mentioned it in the complete error message (though it might have been a little indirect).

Comment: @AdrienGivry nope, i just put 100 randomly, the size of it is given as parameter(int size)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yea, using std::vector is way easier than arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or should I use std::vector instead?

That's a great idea.

```
class Multime
{
private:
    std::vector<int> elemente;
public:
    Multime() {}
    Multime(std::vector<int> el) : elemente(std::move(el)) {}
};

int main()
{
    Multime m1 = Multime({ 1, 2, 3 });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would have been even better if you used a constructor initializer list. ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good idea. I keep forgetting about this feature way too often.

Comment: Better: `elemente(std::move(el))`.

Comment: Thanks you, I decided it is better to use **std::vector** but instead of `move`, I used `push_back`                                                                     
`Multime(vector<int> el, int s){
        this -> size = s;
        for(int i = 0; i < this -> size; i++)
            this -> elemente.push_back(el[i]);`

Comment: @Andrei, don't do it. 1) You take `el` by copy, but you don't store that copy inside your object using a move-constructor. Copying is redundant: take `el` by const-reference. 2) `push_back`ing in a loop causes redundant reallocations: preallocate space with `elemente.reserve(s);` before the loop. 3) Don't use `int` for a vector's size, use `std::size_t` and be consistent with the standard library.

Comment: @Andrei 4) You don't need the second argument. `std::vector` knows its size, you can obtain it with `.size()`. With all these in mind, just take `el` by value and use `std::move`. It is short, self-explanatory, and will automatically take care about lvalue/rvalue arguments passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your class to be able to contain a varying number of elements (Defined at compile time), you can try:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t _Size>
class Multime
{
private:
    int elemente[_Size];
public:
    Multime() {}

    Multime(const std::array<int, _Size>& p_elements)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _Size; ++i)
            this->elemente[i] = p_elements[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Multime<3> m1({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

You can also directly store an std::array into your class, so the construction is cleaner

```
#include <array>

template <size_t _Size>
class Multime
{
private:
    std::array<int, _Size> elemente;
public:
    Multime() {}
    Multime(const std::array<int, _Size>& p_elements) : elemente(p_elements) {}
};

int main()
{
    Multime<3> m1({1, 2, 3});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::array` member also would simplify constructor too.

Comment: It's up to him, I didn't want to break his logic

Comment: The name `_Size` is reserved. Change it to `_size` or `Size`, any name that starts with an underscore followed by a capital is reseved to the standard